# Cannot grant privileges to Azure MySql Datanase

Tags: mysql, azure

Hello I am having serious issues granting privileges to the only user in an azure database. I am logged on to MySql workbench to the user that azure auto provides me, but when I try to connect through a program that I am making I using the same connection string i am getting access denied errors.

I am trying to grant all privileges to the default user using the following code in mysql but I am getting accessed denied

```
GRANT ALL ON databasename.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%';
```

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I do not have the password for the user root, I only have the username and password azure has provided me with apparently

Comment: Are you logged in as root?

Comment: Im logged in with the username and password azure provide me with in the dashboard panel below the connection string

Comment: Can you try running the command as root user?

Comment: If I change my username to 'root' I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: Hmm can you try this while logged in as root: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<PASS>';`

Comment: Im unsure what you mean as looged in as root as I dont have the password for it as its a database in the cloud. the only way I can currently log in to it is to provide my host name and type in the username and password that azure has provided me to this database.

Comment: I am suggesting that you log in as root on MySQL workbench

Comment: I am assuming you are using cleardb mysql, and you are able to connect to the MySQL db using MySQL workbench from your laptop/desktop, and you are unable to connect to MySQL using a different program running on the same machine. If my assumption is correct, can you please give more information regarding the language/library you are using to connect to MySQL from your program?

Comment: Hey Mani, When I try to do a basic select statement from the online database in the cloud from a visual studio web form application on a different laptop within the same network I get the error "ACCESS DENIED FOR USER (MYUSERNAME)" I am using the connection string that azure is providing me and im using the mysql visual studio connector.. I was previously using a free azure database but I wanted to get a new one with more connections.

Comment: Hey Bunion, did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used nugget to get MySQL.Data in my web form project (vs 2015), and adding the cleardb connection string in the code below worked for me. I am also able to connect using MySQL workbench from the same machine as well. This should work for you as well. please check and let me know.

```
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
    string myConnectionString;

    myConnectionString = "<your cleardb conn string>";

    try
    {
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
        conn.Open();
        System.Data.ConnectionState state =  conn.State;
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the late reply